# Turing machine that erase its input

Tags: turing-machines

I have got this question :
Consider a Turing machine Cw which erases its input, writes w on the tape, and halts while scanning the leftmost character of w. Design the Turing machine C011

I need explanation what is actual the question is and what Cw does. I kind of understand it writes empty symbol on every input it gets but the rest is unclear to me. Hope someone can help me understand the question and what is required me to  do.

Comment: Smells like homework. This question is better suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case w = 011.

Indeed, the TM should first overwrite the entire input. I think we can assume that the input does not have gaps. So as soon as the TM reads an empty space on the input tape, it should begin writing 011.

When writing the second 1, enter into a state for which there do not exist any transitions. This way you ensure that the machine halts on that position. Nothing is said explicitely about whether this state should be accepting, but it would make sense to have it as the unique accepting state.